# Can not convert type AnonymousType?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, partial-views, anonymous-types

I want to pass the results of a query (JSON) from a controller to a partial view, that's why I created a strongly type  as follows:

```
public class Suivi_Client
{
    public string ClientID { get; set; }
     public string Activite { get; set; }
     public string ClientName { get; set; }
}

// list 
public class Suivis
{
    public List<Suivi_Client> List_Clients { set; get; }
}
```

Then the partial view :

```
 @model IEnumerable<Project.Models.Suivi_Client>
<html>
    <body>
<table border=1>
<thead>
  <tr>
   <th>
    ID
  </th>
   <th>
    Name
  </th>
        <th>
    Activite
  </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
@foreach(var item in Model){
foreach (var pop in item.List_Clients)
{
<tr>
    <td >
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => pop.ClientID)
    </td>
    < <td >
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => pop.ClientName)
    </td>
     <td >
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => pop.Activite)
    </td>

</tr>
}
}
</table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

here is the action method:

```
public ActionResult  Partial_suivi(string clients)
        {
         IEnumerable<Suivis> PopModel;
              var activit = (from x in frh.productivites
                         join y in frh.Clients on x.action equals y.ClientName
                         where x.action.Equals(clients)
                         select new { x.actionID,x.Activité,y.ClientName,y.Responsable,y.TempsCible,x.tempsmoy_ }).Distinct().ToArray();
        PopModel = activit;
            return PartialView(PopModel);
        }
```

but I have this error :  Can not convert type 'AnonymousType # 1 []' to 'Project.Models.Suivis

how can I resolve this error ?

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple issues here.

In your Action Method, you are trying to pass an `IEnumerable<Suivis>` to your view.

But your view is expecting an `IEnumerable<Suivi_Client>`.

The next problem is your linq query is `select`ing (transforming) into an anonymous object, but you're trying to put it into an `IEnumerable<Suivis>`.

I'm going to take a guess that what you want to do is make your linq query select into an `IEnumerable<Suivi_Client>` so that your view can do it's work.  To do that you would change your code to something similar to this

```
IEnumerable<Suivi_Client> PopModel = (from x in frh.productivites
                                      join y in frh.Clients on x.action equals y.ClientName
                                      where x.Action.Equals(clients)
                                      select new Suivi_Client 
                                         { 
                                             Activite = x.Activite,
                                             ClientName = y.ClientName,
                                             ClientID = ??
                                         }).Distinct();

return PartialView(PopModel);
```

There are a lot of unknowns from the code you provided, and you're using objects that you didn't show in your code snippets.  If you could explain what you want your linq query to do actually do, I'm sure someone could post a more complete/better example of how to achieve what you're after.